# Firebase check for existing email with relative/wildcard path

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to check the emails of my users in my firebase database, if their email already exists. My json looks like that:

[image]

I dont know how to get the full path to *email*, because every User starts with the Unique Identifier and I dont have that information. Is it possible to use a wildcard /users/*/email or something like that?

```
this.afdb.database.ref('users/*/email').orderByChild('email').on('value', (snapshot)=>{
  console.log(snapshot);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When a Firebase Database query runs against a location, it considers each child node under that location. And for each child node you can test the value of properties at a known path under that child.

There is no support for wildcards, nor does one seem needed for your case here:

```
this.afdb.database.ref('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo("pqoo@poam.com").on('value', (snapshot)=>{
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(child.val());
  });
});
```

So the two changes are:

1. We query location `users` order by `email` and only return nodes with value `pqoo@poam.com`.
2. There will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. So we use `snapshot.forEach(...)` to loop over the results.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I get a warning: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "email" at /users to your security rules for better performance.  I would do like this? "users": {
      ".indexOn": "email"
    }